# Problems saving a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I've been trying to implement Core Data into my application, and most recently, trying to set a to-many relationship. I set the relationship below

```
NSMutableSet *todoObjects = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [allTodolistsData count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [allTodolistsData objectAtIndex:i];
    TodolistObject *tempTodolist = [[TodolistObject alloc] initWithDict:dictionary];
    [todoObjects addObject:[Todolists newTodolist:tempTodolist withContext:appDelegate.context]];
    [tempTodolist release];
}

[project setTodolists:todoObjects];
```

The project variable is an `NSManagedObject`, and the `setTodolists:` method is auto-generated to set the to-do lists for the project. Since the project has a to-many relationship with the set of to-do lists, I pass in an NSMutableSet. When I do this, however, I get the following error:

**-[__NSArrayM isEqualToSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa325d60**

I can't seem to find anyone who has had this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted my code to show that I am not - todoObjects is an NSMutableSet

Comment: The data SHOULD be a set in Core Data

Comment: Yes. I understand that its not, and that it looks like it thinks the todoObjects set is an array. The info I posted is the info given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the mutable set for the relationship back from your NSManagedObject and add your new objects to it, thusly:

```
NSMutableSet *todoObjects = (NSMutableSet*)[project mutableSetValueForKey:@"todoLists"];

// Switch your for loop to use fast-enumaration
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in allTodolistsData) {
    TodolistObject *tempTodolist = [[TodolistObject alloc] initWithDict:dictionary];
    [todoObjects addObject:[Todolists newTodolist:tempTodolist withContext:appDelegate.context]];
    [tempTodolist release];
}

// Save project in the same context where you created the object
```